# Automating default apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey, controlpanel

I'm trying to automatically change from Edge to IE11 and from Mail to Outlook 2016 on multiple computers. I'm using Autohotkey to change it through the GUI until the process is fully automated using Windows group policy or similar.

My problem is that Windows 10 opens different windows, sometimes this opens the Settings app, and sometimes the good old Control Panel:

```
control /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram
```

The problem with the Settings app is, that is seems to be random if the "Are you sure you want to switch?" button comes up when you switch from the Mail program to Outlook. It always comes up when you try to change from Edge to IE11.

Is there any way to open the control panel "Set your default programs" on every computer but not the frustrating new "Settings" app?

Comment: Instead of changing the default browser, set IE to default and add a hotkey to open Edge.

Comment: I share your frustration with the "random" changes around settings. With each release, they remove more and more from control panel and shift things around. I personally would get GPO working with something like [this](https://theitbros.com/config-microsoft-edge-settings-using-gpo/). GPO really is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

check this AutoHotkey script, I got it to change the default browser to chrome (the 3rd one on the list)

```
Run %comspec% /c "control /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram"
sleep, 2000
sendinput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Space}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Tab}
sleep, 100
SendInput, {Space}
return
```